# How to specify different radiobutton with different styles in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, elementstyle

I am trying to develop a shiny app that contains several panels and each panel has some radio buttons. My current problem is: when I try to specify a certain radio button's style like the below codes, the CSS automatically applies to other radio buttons in whole app.

```
fluidRow(column(12, align='center',h4(tags$style(HTML(".radio-inline {margin-right: 200px;}"))), 
radioButtons("MPL1",label="",choiceNames=c("(60, 0; 12, 1)","(56, 0; 48, 1)"),
choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T))),
```

Some people mention I need to use #inputID, but this trick does not work for my case. After I replace ".radio-inline" with "#MPL1", the codes are invalid (the app can be opened, but the buttons is of the default style).

```
fluidRow(column(12, align='center',h4(tags$style(HTML("#MPL1 {margin-right: 200px;}"))), 
radioButtons("MPL1",label="",choiceNames=c("(60, 0; 12, 1)","(56, 0; 48, 1)"),
choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T))),
```

Could you please tell me where I make mistakes? Any help would be welcome. Thank you very much!

WU

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `class` inside a `div()`.  Then this affects all items defined with that `class`.

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, align='center', 
                  div(class="MPL", radioButtons("MPL1",label="",choiceNames=c("(60, 0; 12, 1)","(56, 0; 48, 1)"),
                               choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T)))),
  fluidRow(column(12, align='center', h4(tags$style(HTML(".radio-inline {margin-right: 100px;}"))),
                  radioButtons("MPL2",label="",choiceNames=c("(61, 0; 12, 1)","(55, 0; 48, 1)"),
                               choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T))),
  fluidRow(column(12, align='center',h4(tags$style(HTML(".MPL .radio-inline {margin-right: 300px;}"))),
                  div(class="MPL", radioButtons("MPL3",label="",choiceNames=c("(62, 0; 12, 1)","(54, 0; 48, 1)"),
                               choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T)) ) ),
  fluidRow(column(12, align='center',
                  radioButtons("MPL4",label="",choiceNames=c("(63, 0; 12, 1)","(53, 0; 48, 1)"),
                               choiceValues=c(0,1),selected= character(0),inline=T)))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```